# numpy: split matrix by indexes

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix and I want to get two different matrixes depending on a list of rows. The indexes are created randomly. I know how the get the first part:

```
indexes = np.random.randint(low=0, high=num_rows size=splitsize)
part1 = data[indexes, :]
```

How do I get the other part of the data?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use `numpy.sediff1d` to get index of the "other" part and that use that to index the matrix.

```
In [24]: num_rows = 8

In [25]: indexes = [2,3,5]

In [26]: other = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(num_rows), indexes)

In [27]: other
Out[27]: array([0, 1, 4, 6, 7])
```

Comment: Replace `8` with `num_rows` for a generic code? Also, using `np.in1d(np.arange(num_rows), indexes)` for boolean selecting the rows might be faster.